# checkbox not working with ajax and jquery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

UPDATE: Looks like the "data-val='true' attribute of the rendered input field causes the error.
the Html.CheckBoxFor() generates this html

```
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true">
                <input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
```

If i use that exact code in my View but delete the "data-val='true'" attribute, it works correctly.

---

I am getting javascript error when trying to submit a form using Ajax.BeginForm() in MVC 4 and jquery 1.10.2. The problem seems to be caused by the checkbox input, because if i remove the checkbox input field it works fine. It also works fine if i use jquery 1.8.3.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u jquery-1.10.2.js:550

Any ideas?

Thanks

Below is the block of code that I use

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "loginForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBox("RememberMe", new { @checked = "checked" })
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="loginSubmitButton" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") if you don't have an account.
    </p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.RedirectUrl)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `isChecked`parameter in the `Html.CheckBox` helper, instead of the `htmlAttributes` parameter?

Comment: I tried Html.CheckBox("RememberMe",true) and @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @checked = "checked" }), and neither works.

Comment: Why don't you set `RememberMe` to `true` in the GET action of the controller where you generate the `LoginModel`?

Comment: I tried that initially but didnt work either

Comment: line 550 is window.JSON.parse(data), are you doing anything with json?

Comment: there is no json or any custom jquery attached to the submit form. I just use the ajax.beginform to post back to server.

Comment: for Ajax.BeginForm I put the post method inside the ajax options. The way you have it, it looks like html.beginform ... something like this new AjaxOptions {
     UpdateTargetId = something,
     HttpMethod = "Post" ....

Comment: Moving the "Post" into AjaxOptions makes no different

Comment: this may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928170/ajax-beginform-with-checkbox-syntax-error

Comment: Thanks for the link NKD. Now I know it's not just me that get the weird behavior.

Comment: No problem. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ValidationMessageFor` for the URL:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RedirectUrl)
```